# addClass does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

Here is a simple "addClass" function that I am trying but it does not work. Should be a simple thing sitting somewhere in the code ))). The text should  change colour based on user's selection in radioGroup1 in here http://jsfiddle.net/PatrickObrian/gdb5t/

HTML

```
<div class="test">Information that I want to be coloured</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" id="A" name="RadioGroup1" value="Y">Yes</label>
    <br>
   <label><input type="radio" id="B" name="RadioGroup1" value="N">No</label>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
 $('input[type=radio][name=RadioGroup1]').change(function(){
 if (this.value == 'Y') {
        $('.test').addClass("classGreen");
}
else if (this.value == 'N') {
        $('.test').addClass("classRed");
}
    }


</script>
```

CSS

```
.classGreen {color: green} 
.test {font-size:24px}
.classRed {color: red}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove other color class name, and also your check the click event:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=RadioGroup1]').click(function(){
    if (this.value == 'Y') {
       $('.test').removeClass("classRed").addClass("classGreen");
    }
    else if (this.value == 'N') {
       $('.test').removeClass("classGreen").addClass("classRed");
    }
});
```

and also I don't know but this worked for CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.test { font-size:24px }
.classRed { color: red }
.classGreen { color: green } 
</style>
```

:)

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the previous associated class, and then add the new class.

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('input[type=radio][name=RadioGroup1]').change(function () {
        if (this.value == 'Y') {
            $('.test').removeClass('classRed').addClass("classGreen");
        } else if (this.value == 'N') {
            $('.test').removeClass('classGreen').addClass("classRed");
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yG4ke/)

Also in the fiddle there were many other problem

- jQuery was not included
- the style part was not proper
- there were syntax errors

---

A shorter way is to use toggleClass()

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('input[type=radio][name=RadioGroup1]').change(function () {
        $('.test').toggleClass("classGreen", this.value == 'Y');
        $('.test').toggleClass("classRed", this.value != 'Y');
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JWy39/)

Comment: @Alexander the `$` means `jQuery`. If you use it, it must be included.

Comment: Is the following line will be sufficient in my html to include jQuery? <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yeh, got it. The problem is - it does NOT work in Dreamweaver. I copied code exactly from JSFiddle into a newly created file, made reference to jQuery - nope. dead.((((

Comment: @Alexander you may have to wrap your code in a dom ready handler

Comment: @Alexander also check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: I even included the jQuery file itself into the <head> of the file - still dead((((

Comment: can you share the html of the complete file

Comment: No - I checked it using IE and Chrome, both give no error. Plus this is NOT the first js code I am using.

Comment: Here is the entire file is wrapped into HTML section for consistency, as it stays in DW.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48188/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-alexander)

Comment: @Alexander: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ tells you everything you need to know to get started with jQuery. The whole purpose of tutorials is guide those unfamiliar with a language or library, like yourself.

Comment: @Felix - in the process of learning!)) Thanx. That's why I am asking questions)))))

Comment: @Alexander: And many of those question will be automatically answered by reading tutorials and guides. Don't get me, it's good to ask question, but Stack Overflow is not the right place to learn the basics of a language or library.

Comment: @Alexander using [dom ready handler](learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y3b8y/1/